# $\,f:[0,1)\to\mathbb R$ is a concave differentiable function st $\,f(0)=0$. Show that $g:[0,1),g(z)=f(zx)/z$, for $x > 0$ is decreasing

Tags: convex-optimization

**Question:**
Suppose that $f : [0, 1) \to\mathbb R$ is a concave differentiable function such that $\,f(0) = 0$. Show that $g : [0, 1) \to\mathbb R$ defined by
$g(z) = f(zx)/z$, for some given $x > 0$, is a decreasing function of $z$.

**Thoughts:** I am having quite a lot of trouble with this question and am unsure where to start. A *concave* function satisfies
$$F(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq \lambda\,F(x) + (1-\lambda)\,F(y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

As $f$ is concave and differentiable, it should lie below all its tangents, that is:
$$ f(b)\leq f(a)+f'(a)(b-a) $$
for all $a,b \in[0,1)$.

On the other hand, for $g$ (easily seen to be differentiable on $(0,1)$) we have:

$$g'(z) = \frac{zxf'(zx)-f(zx)}{z^2} $$

which can be proven (using above observation and $f(0)=0$) to be less than or equal to $0$ for all $z\in (0,1)$, hence $g$ is decreasing on $(0,1)$.

*Note:*

Note that $g(0)$ doesn't exist, so one might want to restrict the domain of $g$ to $(0,1)$. Alternatively, one can define $$g(0) := \lim\limits_{t\to 0}g(t) = \lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tx)-f(0)}{t-0}=xf'(0),$$
in which case:
$$ g(0)= xf'(0) \geq g(z)=\frac{f(zx)}{z}$$
for all $z\in (0,1)$, again due to the initial observation. So, in this case, $g$ is decreasing on $[0,1)$.

Note also that one should have $x\in (0,1]$ or should enlarge the domain of $f$, say to $[0,\infty)$, otherwise one can't apply $f$ to $zx$ as it may not be in $[0,1)$.

Comment: @erin You are welcome. If you're comfortable with it, you may want to check it (upper left corner) as accepted. Accepting an answer is relevant for this website performance statistics.

Comment: This is really stupid but how did you get g′(z)=[zxf′(zx)−f(zx)]/z^2

Comment: Basically, from $g'(z)=\left(\frac{h(z)}{k(z)}\right)'=\frac{h'(z)k(z)-h(z)k'(z)}{k^2(z)}$, where $h(z)=f(zx)$ and $k(z)=z$ for all $z$. And remember that $x$ is a constant here.

Comment: Thanks. That was really silly of me. my brain has turned to mush

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the case $x=1$: $\displaystyle g(z) = \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}$.  What is that the slope of?